# How to customize the width of <ReactTooltip/>

Tags: reactjs, tooltip

I am using a ReactTooltip and need to change its width dynamically based on the length of the content. How to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

```
<ReactTooltip place='right' className={"tooltip"} />

.tooltip 
{
width: 250px;
white-space : normal;[If necessary]
}
```

Add a customized class and set the width property.